# Yii count items where value is not distinct

Tags: php, yii, distinct

This sounds like this should be fairly straight forward but i'm struggling to find the answer. I'm using Yii, and a table has 4 records, each record has a value, i want to be able to count where this value **is not distinct**

Here's my function currently

```
public function getSessionsDistinctCount(){

        // Create DBCriteria
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select = 'event_id';
        $criteria->distinct = false;

        // Find All related sessions
        $model = Session::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $count = count($model);
        return $count;
    }
```

My tbl looks something like this;

```
id | event_id | title
1  | 2        | name1
2  | 3        | name2
3  | 4        | name3
4  | 4        | name5
```

I want this to return the value of 2 - how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
public function getSessionsDistinctCount(){

    // Create DBCriteria
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = 'event_id';
    $criteria->group = 'event_id';
    // Count events that appear at least twice
    $criteria->having = 'COUNT(*) > 1';

    // Find All related sessions
    $count = Session::model()->count($criteria);
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: This still returns all results

Comment: Ah, it should be 'COUNT(*) > 1', where it count more than 1 record being the same. Thanks for the fix Fabrizio